# Can I power a DC fan from li ion to nimh?

Tags: dc-motor, nimh

I have a mini DC fan with a 2.5mm DC connector connected to a li ion battery provided by the manufacturer.
The li iom battery pack have 4 speeds switch from 3.5V(1.3W) to 7.4V(8W).

The question is can I use the 3xAA rechargeable nimh batteries, 1.2Vx3=3.6V to power the fan?
(And use more AAs to power up to 7.4V?)

Thank you

Comment: What mWh rating do you need?  i.e. time in hours and what do you expect from NiMh?

Comment: Chinging to NiMh primary for the safety concern since the li iom provided by the manufacturer is unlikely reliable. Plus NiMh AA is more easier to get. I hope 4xAAs NiMh can power around 4 hours run time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In raw capacity, *rechargeable NiMh AA Energizer* had 30 percent more energy storage per dollar than the Panasonic Eneloop AAs, so your devices should run a little longer between recharges.
 Your costs may vary.  ($20/8pc) or $7.50 per 3AA's

Some users test results Energizers had an average of 1,888 milliamp hours (mAh) or 2.3 watt hours (Wh) of discharged capacity.

So **3 AA's is 6.9Wh so ~1.3W @ 3.5V will yield 5.3h more or less.**  with ***1000 charge cycles*** at rated capacity current.

Note they advertise 2000mAh at a lower current for 10h.

**Thus the cost to compare is $7.50/6.9Wh = $1.08/Wh**

Then compare cheap Skywolfeye 5 X 5800mAh Li-ion 18650 3.7V $10
which are probably only 1200mAh not 5800 (fake) are expected to be ...
$10/5x5.8Ahx3.7V= $0.09/W but probably $10/5x1.2Ahx3.5V = $0.38/W and some may last a few cycles while others 250 cycles. you YGWYPF ($) buyer beware!

Answer (score 0):

Power delivery only should be fine, recharging will be a different issue.

However, do expect less run time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any details about how many run time lessen given the same capacity? A half? Quarter the run time? Thank you