# How to calculate 18650 battery use time?

Tags: battery-operated, power-consumption

I am currently powering my mini fan using a normal power bank (the one used for smartphone) which is 5V, 2A output and can last for around 6-7 hours.

If I power my fan using two 18650 3.7V 2300mAh (7.4V output) batteries, how long could these two batteries power my fan? (The fan allows up to 9-10V input)

Thank you

Comment: We need to know the current/power drawn by the fan. It should be printed on it, but this may be the worst-case value.

Comment: See this Q and A : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/372547/152903

Comment: What is mAh capacity of your current "normal power bank"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the "a normal power bank" uses the very same 18650 battery with same 2300 mAh capacity, the problem has the following solution:

Step 1: determine the mini-fan power rating. The normal 18650 battery (3.7 V 2300 mAh) has total rated capacity of 3.7 * 2.3 = 8.5 W-hours. The powerbank must have a DC-DC converter to 5 V output. Assuming efficiency of the converter as 80%, the effective capacity of the "a power bank" is about 7 Wh. Since the mini-fan can run for about 7 hours, we can conclude that the fan rated power is 1 W. This is at 5 V power supply.

Now, if you use TWO 18650 cells of the same kind as in "a normal power bank", and design another power bank with 5-V output and assuming the same DC-DC efficiency, the mini-fan will last TWICE AS LONG, by simple arithmetic.

Step 2. But if you plan to feed the mini-fan  with 7.4V (two batteries) directly, the following calculations may apply. Without DC-DC conversion, the capacity of two-cell battery will be about 17 W-hours. However, the mini-fan motor will be running at 7.4 V instead of 5 V, so it might be consuming (7.4/5)^2 = 2.2 times more, or about 2.2 W. So the runtime will be about 17/2.2 = 7.7 hours, only 10% longer than the original setup from "a normal power bank". It might, however, move more air over that time.